# Scandit Barcode Scanner Shows Blank camera on scanning

Tags: xamarin, barcode-scanner

I am trying to implement scandit barcode scanner in my application.i downloaded its sample demo and its works fine.

same code i tried to implement in my app.but it shows black screen on scanning .
I gave camera access also. cant find any thing missing.

Please help if someone also faced same issue. any suggestion most appreciated. 
thanks in advance

This is my code

```
    using FormBot.ViewModels.Abstract;
using Scandit.BarcodePicker.Unified;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Input;
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace FormBot.ViewModels
{
 public class SerialNumberViewModel: BaseViewModelDemo
{
    private string _recognizedCode;

    public ICommand StartScanningCommand => new Command(async () => await StartScanning());

    public string RecognizedCode
    {
        get
        {
            return (_recognizedCode == null) ? "" : "Code scanned: " + _recognizedCode;
        }

        set
        {
            _recognizedCode = value;
        }
    }

    public SerialNumberViewModel()
    {

        ScanditService.ScanditLicense.AppKey = "Key";
        ScanditService.BarcodePicker.DidScan += BarcodePickerOnDidScan;
    }

    private async void BarcodePickerOnDidScan(ScanSession session)
    {
        RecognizedCode = session.NewlyRecognizedCodes.LastOrDefault()?.Data;
        await ScanditService.BarcodePicker.StopScanningAsync();
    }

    private async Task StartScanning()
    {
        await ScanditService.BarcodePicker.StartScanningAsync(false);
    }
}
```

}

in app.xaml.cs

```
 private static string appKey = "key";
 ScanditService.ScanditLicense.AppKey = appKey;
```

Comment: maybe show some of your code, we can't just guess at random possible answers for you.

Comment: @Digitalsa1nt i updated que with code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

set `android:hardwareAccelerated="true"` in `AndroidManifest.xml` file worked for me.